# Maven plugin warning about calling `equals' on incompatible types

Tags: java, maven, equals, static-analysis

NetBeans has the neat feature to warn then calling equals on incompatible types. Since we have wasted countless hours on multiple occasions after changing the return type of some interface I would like to have a maven plugin warning or better fail when calling `equals` on incompatible types.

Comment: Please provide an example

Comment: @lifeisfoo an example would be "a string".equals(new Integer(3))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*findbugs* can detect those things, like incompatible types: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EQ_CHECK_FOR_OPERAND_NOT_COMPATIBLE_WITH_THIS

There is a maven plugin available: http://gleclaire.github.io/findbugs-maven-plugin/

It is also possible to use sonarqube to detect this: http://www.sonarqube.org/
(among a lot of other thigs as well, try to start small)